# Compare 2 Spark dataframes, get the records which are not in both dataframes based on multiple columns

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two PySpark DataFrames. I am looking for records which are not in both datasets based on specific columns.

Sample datasets:

```
# Prepare Data
data_1 = [("A", 1, "data_1"), \
    ("A", 1, "data_1"), \
    ("A", 1, "data_1"), \
    ("A", 2, "data_1")
  ]

# Create DataFrame
columns= ["col_1", "col_2", "source"]
df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(data = data_1, schema = columns)
df_1.show(truncate=False)


# Prepare Data
data_2 = [("A", 1, "data_2"), \
    ("A", 1, "data_2"), \
    ("A", 1, "data_2"), \
    ("A", 3, "data_2")
  ]

# Create DataFrame
columns= ["col_1", "col_2", "source"]
df_2 = spark.createDataFrame(data = data_2, schema = columns)
df_2.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

[image]

I want to compare above DataFrames based on columns `col_1` & `col_2` and get the records which are only in one of the DataFrames. The expected results are:

| col_1 | col_2 | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "A" | 2 | "data_1" |
| "A" | 3 | "data_2" |

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do LEFT_ANTI based on two columns which will give you the records present in one dataframe but missing from another. You can then union both the outputs.

```
// Use comma separated string instead of colList in case of python
Dataset<Row> missingInRight = leftDF.join(rightDF, colList, "left_anti");
Dataset<Row> missingInLeft = rightDF.join(leftDF, colList, "left_anti");
missingInRight.union(missingInLeft).show();
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+------+
|col_1|col_2|source|
+-----+-----+------+
|    A|    2|data_1|
|    A|    3|data_2|
+-----+-----+------+
```

You can also add a column to tell you which dataframe didn't had the record.

```
Dataset<Row> missingInRight = leftDF.join(rightDF, colList, "left_anti")
      .withColumn("Comment", functions.lit("NOT_IN_RIGHT"));

Dataset<Row> missingInLeft = rightDF.join(leftDF, colList, "left_anti")
       .withColumn("Comment", functions.lit("NOT_IN_LEFT"));
missingInRight.union(missingInLeft).show();
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+------+------------+
|col_1|col_2|source|     Comment|
+-----+-----+------+------------+
|    A|    2|data_1|NOT_IN_RIGHT|
|    A|    3|data_2| NOT_IN_LEFT|
+-----+-----+------+------------+
```

In case of comparing all the columns, you can use "except"

```
leftDF.except(rightDF)
```